# Write a query using INNER JOIN AND OR

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a form and an insert button and when i click on the button - the fields goes in to these tables (i didn't put here all the fields because they are not important for my question).

The Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE SafetyAct (
SafetyAct_id int identity(1,1),
Username varchar(50),
SafetyType_id int,
constraint pk_SafetyAct_id 
           primary key (SafetyAct_id),
constraint fk_Users_SafetyAct 
           foreign key(Username) 
           references Users(Username)
           on delete cascade
)
CREATE TABLE Product (
Product_id int identity(1,1) primary key,
SafetyAct_id int,
Cause_id int,
constraint fk_SafetyAct_Product
           foreign key(SafetyAct_id)
           references SafetyAct(SafetyAct_id)
           on delete cascade,
constraint fk_Cause_Product
           foreign key(Cause_id)
           references Cause(Cause_id) 
           on delete cascade
)
CREATE TABLE SafetyIntervention (
SafetyIntervention_id int identity(1,1) primary key,
SafetyAct_id int,
Cause_id int,
constraint fk_SafetyAct_SafetyIntervention 
           foreign key(SafetyAct_id)
           references SafetyAct(SafetyAct_id)
           on delete cascade,
constraint fk_Cause_SafetyIntervention
           foreign key(Cause_id)
           references Cause(Cause_id)
           on delete cascade
)
CREATE TABLE Cause (
Cause_id int primary key,
Cause_name varchar(80)
)
```

I want to write a query that shows the fields - SafetyAct_id and Cause_name. 
in the Cause_name field i have a problem because i want that the query will show me the cause name drom the Product table **or** from the SafetyIntervension table (of course to connect it to the Cause table because i have only the cause_id - foriegn key in these tables) and i don't know how to write INNER JOIN and OR at the same query.

I am new with this so plase be patient.

Thank you!

Comment: what happens if there is a cause in **both** tables?

Comment: because i want to see the Cause name where it was inserted.. i won't have a situation which the cause_id (or cause_name) will be in both tables (Product and Safetyintervention)

Comment: You need to show what you have done so far -- I want to write a query does not show adequate effort and research on your part.

Comment: SELECT     SafetyAct.SafetyAct_id, Cause.Cause_name
FROM   SafetyAct.SafetyAct_id INNER JOIN Cause INNER JOIN Product INNER JOIN InfrastrucOp INNER JOIN SafetyIntervention WHERE
                  Cause.Cause_id = Product.Cause_id OR Cause.Cause_id = SafetyIntervention.Cause_id

Comment: it is not possible that the cause will be in both tables

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  SA.SafetyAct_id,
        C.Cause_name
FROM SafetyAct SA
LEFT JOIN Product P
    ON SA.SafetyAct_id = P.SafetyAct_id
LEFT JOIN SafetyIntervention SI
    ON SA.SafetyAct_id = SI.SafetyAct_id
LEFT JOIN Cause C
    ON ISNULL(P.Cause_id,SI.Cause_id) = C.Cause_id
```

Comment: thank you Lamak! if i have another table like product and SafetyIntervention, the "ISNULL" function will work?

Comment: @user3082812 I'm not if the query can be used the same way, sorry, it would be irresponsible for me to answer that from your comment

Answer (score 0):

An `or` is easy.  So, based on Lamak's code:

```
SELECT SA.SafetyAct_id,
       C.Cause_name
FROM SafetyAct SA LEFT JOIN
     Product P
     ON SA.SafetyAct_id = P.SafetyAct_id LEFT JOIN
     SafetyIntervention SI
     ON SA.SafetyAct_id = SI.SafetyAct_id LEFT JOIN
     Cause C
     ON C.Cause_id = P.Cause_id OR C.Cause_Id = SI.Cause_id;
--------------------------------^
```

You can just use `OR` in the `ON` condition.

However, it is often challenging for a SQL engine (SQL Server included) to optimize a `join` when the `on` condition includes `or` or functions on the columns used for the join.  Hence, the following is often more efficient:

```
SELECT SA.SafetyAct_id,
       COALESCE(Cp.Cause_name, Csi.Cause_Name) as Cause_Name
FROM SafetyAct SA LEFT JOIN
     Product P
     ON SA.SafetyAct_id = P.SafetyAct_id LEFT JOIN
     SafetyIntervention SI
     ON SA.SafetyAct_id = SI.SafetyAct_id LEFT JOIN
     Cause Cp
     ON Cp.Cause_id = P.Cause_id LEFT JOIN
     Cause Csi
     ON Csi.Cause_Id = SI.Cause_id;
```

If only some of the records have a cause of either type, then add:

```
WHERE Cp.Cause_Id IS NOT NULL OR Csi.Cause_Id IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: if i want to add to my query order by i get this error: "The multi-part identifier "SafetyAct.TimeStamp" could not be bound."

Comment: @user3082812 . . . You need to use the table alias:  `sa.TimeStamp`.